# powerbi api authentication - wrong scope

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi, microsoft-graph-api

I try to get the list of the datasets for a particular tenant, using:
`https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets`

I get then a 403 error, it seems that my access code is not suitable for this call.

I could get an access_code successfully but I assume that it has the wrong scope since the response states:
 `"scope": "openid profile email User.Read"`

yet I granted the correct permissions in azure:

[image]

when trying to add in the scope in the authentication call: `openid offline_access DataSet.ReadWrite.All` then I get an invalid_grant error

Comment: Try `openid profile email https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default` as the `scope`.

Comment: works perfectly! If I get it right ```the https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default``` uses all the permissions granted, right ? Would you please mind answer to the question so that I can mark it as solved

Comment: Added the answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `openid profile email https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default` as the `scope`.

You can find this endpoint while adding the power bi permission from Azure Portal:

[image]